# Content Security Policy (CSP) not implemented in Angular

Tags: angular, security, content-security-policy

I have added CSP as below to the index.html files inside the `<head>` tag.

```
<meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="
    script-src 'self';
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; 
    font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;
    img-src 'self' data: https://www.gstatic.com/;"
    />
```

Note: I'm using `style-src 'unsafe-inline'` because I'm using some angular material components and without `'unsafe-inline'`, the styles of angular material components break.

But, my security team still complains that CSP not implemented and according to them, the below paths are without a CSP header.

```
https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/card-details-initial
https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/mysql/main.3550f319f28ebd698940.js
https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/oauth/styles.2b86afa3c6ac02c17f35.css
https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/mysql/assets/images/app_logo/
https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/PMA/main.3550f319f28ebd698940.js
...
```

This is deployed in AWS. Does anyone know a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Please try to add this line in your head tag and remove old one

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

Comment: What does the above line of code do ?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know a workaround for this issue?

The security team should not only show the vulnerabilities, but also provide recommendations on how to eliminate the vulnerabilities.
Therefore ask your security team few questions:

1. What CSP rules they suppose to implement with `*.css` and `*.js` files (*text/css* and *text/javascript* MIME types respectively)?
2. Your web app uses a `<meta>` tag to delivery CSP. Some SPAs unable to use CSP HTTP header at all.
   Question is: how do your security team suppose to use `<meta>` tag in CSS/JS files?
3. Ask them to provide any examples of vulnerability via CSS/JS files which can be solved via CSP header delivered with the file.

Based on the results of answering the questions, you can decide to dismiss your security team or retrain it.

The problem of some "security teams" is that they know how to use the WAS scanner, but they do not know how to interpret its results. Therefore, having received the message "[QID: 150206 Content Security Policy Not Implemented](https://csplite.com/csp286/)" with "vulnerabled" URLs, they do not know what to do about it.

> 

If you are a person who is in charge for web app, follow [check-list](https://csplite.com/csp286/#get_rid_of_CSP_not_implemented) what to do:

1. Get the original scan report from the secrurity team.
2. Check the status codes of vulnerabled URls - nonexistent/erroneous pages (403/404/5xxx/etc) are vulnerable for XSS. Fix such error pages if possible, for others - check does server returns diagnosis HTML-page "Page Not Found"/"Page not exists" with a CSP header.
3. Check the Content-Type header of vulnerabled URls. CSP is useless for files with *text/css* and *text/javasctirt* MIME-types (only Firefox non-standardly supports CSP for  script files used for Workers).
4. Take responsibility and take a final decision which scanner warnings should be fixed and which - ignored.

**Note 1.** If `card-details-initial` in the `https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/card-details-initial` means "bank cards" or some sensitive users data - make double check in all steps.

**Note 2.** Avoid simultaneously publishing Content-Security-Policy header via server config and within aapplication (via HTTP header or meta tag). Two CSPs as the same time can make resulting CSP very restrictive and unpredictable.